# Complex XML to C# classes - how to deserialize them?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

My goal is to extract the data from the XML. But I have some rather complex XML that is not easily converted to C sharp classes.

The XML looks like this:

```
<group.........>
  <suite....>
    <properties>
      <property name=....../>
    </properties>
    <suite type="test">
      <suite type="test1">
        <suite...>    
          <suite...>     
            <suite...>  
              <case id="1000" name="example"> 
                <properties>
                  <property ...../>    
                </properties>
              </case>
              <case.......>
                <properties>
                  <property ...../>      
                </properties>
              </case>
              <case>
                <properties>
                  <property .... />           
                </properties>
              </case>
            </suite>
          </suite>
        </suite>
      </suite>
    </suite>
  </suite>
</group>
```

I have used an online xml to c sharp convert to create classes, but it does not seem to handle the XML structure correctly.

Update:

The XML comes from NUNIT3. It is the result of the UNIT3 console that is written to an XML document.

Update 2:

I am able to extract data using below code - don't know if there is a more elegant solution:

```
XElement resultFile = XElement.Load($"{resultFilePathList}"); 
                var dataFromXML = (
                    from data in resultFile.Descendants("case")
                    select new
                    {
                        caseid = data.Attribute("id").Value,
                        name = data.Attribute("fullname").Value,
                        result = data.Attribute("result").Value,
                        duration = data.Attribute("duration").Value
                    }
                );
```

Comment: Copy the XML to your clipboard, then in in VS, choose Edit/Paste Special/Paste XML as classes.   Except that whoever designed your XML file, didn't create a valid one.

Comment: @Neil Tried that it creates a lot of classes, like multiple classes such as suitesuitesute and suitesuite

Comment: Unless you can get the creator of this XML to 'do it better', you are going to have to parse that XML 'manually', with the help of XmlReader https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmlreader-class/

Comment: @Neil, what is XmlReader used for?

Comment: I'd use [LINQ-to-XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) and `XDocument` before `XmlReader`.

Comment: Either way, I'd be willing to bet whoever wrote the code that created that XML didn't use a conforming library to do so.

Comment: You should use XML Serialization in first instance when generating the XML from classes and when generating classes back from XML
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization

Comment: The XML is output from NUNIT3. I have updated the OP

Comment: @dbc do you have an example of linq to xml with the XML I have provided?

Comment: In case when serialization is out of your control, you can still can control the deserealization. But you will create the classes by hand following the XML format. It is advanced flexible enough.

Comment: @armagedescu: How would you create classes out of the ugly XML I provided?
The only solution I have currently is to use LINQ to XML

Comment: The xml looks like a nested (recursive) set of classes forming a tree with properties at the leaves of the tree.  Not ugly!   So each node of the tree should have a name with a list of children.  I would start by designing the classes.  You would need a custom parser and recommend using xml Linq.  The extraction code would be a recursive algorithm.  I have written lots of code like this before.

Comment: @jdweng can you supply an example?

Comment: @uba2012 Using LINQ to map XML to classes is the way to invent something that XML serializer already does for you. In your sample I see an XML containing only two classes, <group> and <suite>. 
using System.Xml.Serialization;

Comment: @armagedescu the below solution worked. How would you design classes for the built in serialiser to work on?

Comment: The code using Descents("case") will not correlate the suite tags to the case tags.  You will only get the cases without knowing the parents.

Comment: @uba2012 Please check in the list on answers. You may need to use different name in C# for attributes, because "case" for instance is a keyword, and you will need a different mapping. There are specific annotations that you can add for this purpose. The XML Serializer is flexible enough to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code, is as simple as this

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
.......
StreamReader streamer = new StreamReader("yourgroup.xml");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(group));
group x = (group)serializer.Deserialize(streamer);
streamer.Close();
```

And you have do define your classes, somehow like this

```
public class group {List<suite> suite;}
public class suite
{
   public List<suite> suite;
   public List<property> properties;
}
```

Ok, you can add additional annotation if you need specific handling
For instance if there is "case" element, create your class with different name

```
public class xcase
{
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public Property[] properties;...
}
public class suite
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "case")]
    public xcase[] cases {get; set; } 
    ....
}
```

Comment: My case class has attributes and child property elements. I guess I need to add a case class to.

Comment: @uba2012 add it, but give a different name. 
See this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes

Comment: @uba2012 please check updated answer, I provided a sample how to map the <case> element

Comment: thanks. I guess I only need one suite class right? And why can’t I name the case class case? I don’t get that. I will try your solution tomorrow as it seems like a better solution

Comment: @uba2012 You can't name class "case" because "сase" in is reserved keyword in C#. It is already used for switch/case block. You can't name your class "class", "if", "else", "public" and so on.

Comment: of course. In your answer you have 2 suite classes, I guess only need one right?

Comment: Yes, you need only one.

Comment: it works! but how do I get the ID of a case from object Testrun, x object?

Comment: I added recursion to find the last suite that contains cases and now everything works. I have marked your answer, as it seems more correct. But the other answer also works.

Comment: @uba2012 Yes, the other works. You can find many ways to accomplish some task.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication120
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement group = doc.Root;
            Suite rootSuite = new Suite();
            Suite.ReadXml(group, rootSuite);
        }

    }
    public class Suite
    {
        public List<Suite> suites { get; set; }
        public List<Case> cases { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> properties { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }

        public static void ReadXml(XElement xparentSuite, Suite parentSuite)
        {
            foreach (XElement xSuite in xparentSuite.Elements("suite"))
            {
                parentSuite.type = (string)xSuite.Attribute("type");
                if (parentSuite.suites == null) parentSuite.suites = new List<Suite>();
                Suite newSuite = new Suite();
                parentSuite.suites.Add(newSuite);
                XElement properties = xSuite.Element("properties");
                if (properties != null)
                {
                    parentSuite.properties = properties.Elements("property")
                        .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => (string)y)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
                }
                parentSuite.cases = xSuite.Elements("case").Select(x => new Case(x)).ToList();
                ReadXml(xSuite, newSuite);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Case
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> properties { get; set; }

        public Case() { }
        public Case(XElement _case)
        {
            id = (string)_case.Attribute("id");
            name = (string)_case.Attribute("name");
            properties = _case.Descendants("property")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: why is Case not a class?

Comment: Case could be a class.  Just from the sample xml posted if case just contains KeyValuePair<string,string> I though a dictionary was simpler.

Comment: I updated OP with updated XML. 
I am trying to implement your code, but I guess I need to design the classes first?
I need Suite class (which you supplied)
I need Case class
I need properties class

Am I right?

Comment: I updated code.  As you can see I like using dictionaries.